wine errormessage: wine client error:0: recvmsg: The connection was reset by the communication partner
I Installed wine on my system using box64 and box86 but get the following errormessage: wine client error:0: recvmsg: The connection was reset by the communication partner. I tried removing the ~/.wine folder as suggested by some fixes for other problems. I can't even run winecfg, because I get the same errormessage. I also tried running wine as root. I Also tried
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
but that didn't help.
It's Raspberry Pi OS arm64 on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5 it should be the newest release. I installed wine through "Pi-Apps" but I do not know what Pi-Apps uses to install wine. (probably apt-get install wine ) I have 4GB of Memory if that helps. Neofetch says the os is Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) aarch64
Hope you guys have any suggestions as I'm new to the linux community

You can try to install wine manually.

@liaifat85 Tried it, didn't help
